# Parsing contents of a textfile in C(Deleting parts, storing others)

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I have a basic .txt file that may contain an unknown amount of pieces of data exactly in this format and I need to extract the second part after the '=' identifier. For example:

```
variable1=Hello
variable2=How
variable3=Are
variable4=You?
```

I need to extract "Hello" "How" "Are" and "You?" separately and store them into an array(removing/ignoring the variable name) and being able to call each word individually. I'm doing this in C and here is what I currently have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char*result;
    char copy[256];
    FILE * filePtr;
    filePtr = fopen("testfile.txt", "r+");

    strcpy(copy, "testfile.txt");
    while(fgets(copy, 256, filePtr)!= NULL)
    {
      result = strchr(copy, '=');
      result = strtok(NULL, "=");
      printf("%s",result);
      if(result != 0)
      {
        *result = 0;
      }
    result = strtok(copy, "=");
    }
return 0;
}
```

My current output is

```
(null)How
Are
You?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You do not need `strtok`, using `strchr` is enough.
- no need to copy the filename to the `copy` buffer.
- probably not necessary to open the file in update mode `"%r+"` either.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *words[20];
    int n = 0;
    char *result;
    char copy[256];
    FILE *filePtr;
    filePtr = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(copy, 256, filePtr) != NULL) {
        copy[strcspn(copy, "\n")] = '\0';  /* strip the \n if present */
        result = strchr(copy, '=');
        if (result != NULL) {
            words[n++] = strdup(result + 1);
            printf("%s ", result + 1);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(filePtr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the one liner to strip the trailing `\n` left at the end of `copy` by `fgets()`: `copy[strcspn(copy, "\n")] = '\0';`. It works even if `fgets()` did not see a `\n` before the end of the buffer or before the end of file. `strcspn` counts returns the number of characters in `copy` that are not in the second argument, thus it returns the length of the line without the `\n`.

The words are collected into an array `words` of pointers to strings. Each word is copied into memory allocated by `malloc` by the `strdup` function.  `strdup` is not part of Standard C, but part of Posix and probably present in your environment, possibly written as `_strdup`.

Note also that you should also test for failure to open the file, failure to allocate memory in `strdup`, and also handle more than `20` strings...

If there is a fixed set of words and you just want to strip the initial parts, you can use a simpler hardcoded approach:

```
int main(void) {
    char word1[20], word2[20], word3[20], word4[20];
    FILE *filePtr;
    filePtr = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");

    if (fscanf(filePtr,
               "%*[^=]=%19[^\n]%*[^=]=%19[^\n]%*[^=]=%19[^\n]%*[^=]=%19[^\n]",
               word1, word2, word3, word4) == 4) {
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n", word1, word2, word3, word4);
        // perform whatever task with the arrays
    } else {
        printf("parse failed\n");
    }
    fclose(filePtr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response really appreciate it, a couple questions: On line 14 what is happening with strcspn, is there an alternative than using this function? Secondly, how would I go about storing each individual word into it's own array to be able to use the words elsewhere?

Comment: @shrimpay: I updated the answer.  The words **are** stored in an array you can use somewhere else.  You may need to modify the code to handle more words, possibly an arbitrary amount, and the array itself might need to be allocated with `malloc` to persist after you exit the parsing function.  You should then return the count as well or store an extra `NULL` at the end of the array as an end marker.

Comment: I think I asked the question wrong, I'm attempting to store each word separately in individual arrays, not all in one. So then I can assign say `"Hello" = var1[20]` and `"How "= var2[20]`. Hope that makes sense, I just realized my question asks to separate them, but to store them into the same array which is not what I'm going for.

Comment: If this is your spec, then you know how many strings you are going for and where you want to store them.  Instead of `word[n++] = strdup(result+1);`, write your own code for storing the n-th string.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so not sure how to thank you for your time. I've given you the green check. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @shrimpay: you can upvote the answer once you reach 15 points